# How to define a string variable in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have been working with VB for a while now. Now I'm giving C++ a shot, i have came across strings, i cant seem to find a way to declare a string.

For example in VB:

```
Dim Something As String = "Some text"
```

Or

```
Dim Something As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
```

Whats the equivalent to the code above in C++ ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

C++ supplies a [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class that can be used like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string Something = "Some text";
    std::cout << Something << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

using the standard `<string>` header

```
std::string Something = "Some Text";
```

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/42209-c-strings/

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you can declare a string like this:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1("argue2000"); //define a string and Initialize str1 with "argue2000"    
    string str2 = "argue2000"; // define a string and assign str2 with "argue2000"
    string str3;  //just declare a string, it has no value
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Hey! What about char.  arrays?  char str[30];

Answer (score 1):

Preferred string type in C++ is `string`, defined in namespace `std`, in header `<string>` and you can initialize it like this for example:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string str1("Some text");
   std::string str2 = "Some text";
}
```

More about it you can find [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string).